# Withdrawing from a visa application: any negative impact for future applications?

Tags: visa, student-visa, australia

Due to unprecedented circumstances, I might need to withdraw from my current student visa application (Australia) and re-apply next year. Will this be considered as a negative point for my future application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is virtually certain that withdrawing from an as yet ungranted Visa Application of any nature in Australia will create no prejudice against a future application even for the same Visa class.

Considering the class is a Student Visa, and that you identify circumstances that seem to be outside your personal control, I feel doubly confident this will not create a negative problem for you.

OTOH, you had best withdraw the application ASAP, because once granted, it would likely create hurdles including perhaps a barrier for application for a period of time.